# React Native default width

Tags: react-native, components, width

This might be a stupid question but I don't understand how components width works.

When I do :

```
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ height: 100, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}></View>
        )
    }
```

My yellow view is visible, takes 100 "height" and **full width**.
Why ? I never set a width, why width is not equal to 0 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The height of your view is 100 because you set as such
2. The width of your view is *not* zero because you didn't set it to 0, and zero is NOT the default width value

   - *the default value of width is 'auto' because you didn't set it to anything else ('auto' basically 100% of the 'remaining' space of the parent unless other styles make it behave otherwise ie: flex).*

**The Solution!**

- Just set your width to what you want it to be, either explicitly or with flex

Comment: Ok clear answer. I still don't understand why width is 'auto' by defaut when height seems to not be 'auto'. I means, if I just create a view with <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}></View> => height and width should be 'auto' right ? Why my view is not visible in this case so ?

Comment: Another example, just try : <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}><View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}></View></View>. Red view should have height and width 'auto' and still it doesn't appear !

Comment: The [`View` docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#docsNav) state that `View` maps to the native equivalent on whatever platform React Native is running … [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview), [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), [`android.view`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), etc. Depending on platform, the default measurement and its behavior in relation to parent and children can vary. It may help to reference the docs relevant to your platform (linked above).

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it doesn't answer my question. There is a behavior that seems to be different between height and width in ReactNative ! This is like width is auto by default where height is not. If height and width are auto by default then <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}></View> should display my view in full screen right ? But this not the case. As for me, width is auto by default  like Mohammed said, but height is not. I think I'm wrong but I can't figured it out.

Comment: Traditionally containers in web applications (apps in general) default to a height of 0 and a width of 'auto'. First a **default** is just a value that is set when there is no explicit value provided. There is no real concrete logic to dictate what is and isn't a default besides objective reasoning, hence the default normally conforms to what is perceived as common or intelligent uses. Besides that there is not too much to try to understand or agree with as there is just to remember and move on. (the life of a developer)

Comment: if you desire your height to be 100%, just set `flex: 1` on the parent container and now your parent has height equal to 100% .

Answer (score 2):

Both width and height by default have the value of "auto", but there is a different behavior for width and height.
If you don't specify height, it will be 0, on the other hand if you don't specify width, it will take all the space of the parent.

This is because of the alignItems style of the parent. In React Native, each component has this style by default:

```
alignItems: "stretch"
```

This means that children of this component, should take all the space in the cross axis, which is width of the parent. That's why width and height have different functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Well a view basically wraps to the height and width of it's children unless you pass it both a height and a width. But to achieve what you want you could use flex. For example

```
<View style={{flex: 1, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'yellow' />
```

Would give it a width of 100 and full height.

[More on flex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, I want to know why when I set only height on a view, it takes all the width ? I means I only set a height, why width is not equal to 0 ? I edited my question, it was poorly formulated my bad.

Answer (score 0):

React Native uses the Yoga layout engine internally, which is based of the CSS Flexbox specification. In CSS, the width and height of a *Block Level element* (the only type RN supports) is set to *auto* by default.

When the width of a Block Level element is set to auto, it will expand to the largest possible width it can, without exceeding the width of it's parent element.

You can read the part of the spec that deals with it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins), although note that it isn't exactly an easily understandable document.